# Foreign key insert situation

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys

I have two tables: **family**  AND **people**.

The people table has the following fields:

```
+----+------+-----+--------+-----------+
| id | name | age | gender | family_id |
+----+------+-----+--------+-----------+
```

The family table has the following fields:

```
+-----------+
| family_id |
+-----------+
```

The family 'family_id' is a **foreign key** to id in the people table.

I want to add a new row to people table.

```
id = 5, name = "Bradd Pit", age = 40, gender = "m"
```

the id in people table should be equal to family_id in family table

Do I need to make two insert commands? one to family table and one to people table?

**edit:** family has only one table because when I delete a family -> all the people in the family will also be deleted

Comment: What's the sense of a table with only one field?

Comment: the sense is that when i delete a family -> all the people in the family will also be deleted

Comment: @user3282988 For that you can use `DELETE FROM people where id={family_id}`.

Comment: yes. But i want to add (insert) a new row to people.
that means i need to insert family table an id before?

Comment: @user3282988 Dude, still you are missing the point. **Why do you need a single field table ?** If you want to delete all members in a family modify my sql to this 
`DELETE FROM people where family_id={family_id}`

Comment: @eggyal Considering efficiency. I think it is not worth to make a table for only cascade delete.

Answer (score 1):

> The family 'family_id' is a foreign key to id in the people table.

You have this relationship backwards. The `people.family_id` should be a foreign key to the `family.family_id` table.

```
CREATE TABLE family (
  famliy_id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE people (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT,
  age TINYINT UNSIGNED,
  gender CHAR(1),
  family_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (family_id) REFERENCES family(family_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The answer to your question is yes, you need to insert to `family` separately, and *before* you can insert to `people`. In SQL, an INSERT statement can insert to only one table at a time.

There could be a way to write a trigger before insert for the `people` table, which uses INSERT IGNORE to insert the family_id to `family` just in case it isn't there already (and the IGNORE part means it's not an error if the value is already in that table). But I wouldn't do this, it's needless overhead to run a trigger for this case.

> family has only one table because when i delete a family -> all the people in the family will also be deleted

This doesn't require a second `family` table at all. It's true that the foreign key allows you to `DELETE FROM family WHERE family_id = 123`, and the cascading delete affects the people table.

But if you didn't have the `family` table or the foreign key referencing it, you could still delete from the `people` table, and in fact it would actually be more efficient to simply `DELETE FROM people WHERE family_id = 123`.

If there's something more complex about your model that you aren't telling us, like multiple child tables referencing `family`, then it might be worthwhile to have the cascading foreign key to simplify deletions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming id in table people actually means family_id. In this case, you need two inserts if 5 is not in the family table.

But something about this design is broken. You don't need table family if it has only a field.